# I am facing a problem with the navigation menu of my website

Tags: menus, javascript, navigation

The link to my website is http://ashevilleandbeyond.com/ and when you load it on your browser, for a few initial loading seconds, you will notice that the menu items are visible at the top left side of the website along with the logo. I don't know what to do about it. The menu items are supposed to be activated if someone clicks on the menu button on the top right corner of the website. I don't have a clue about it.
I would really appreciate some help from your side.

Here is a screenshot. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your javascript (which is formatting your menu) is only running after page load. You have quite a few includes so I didn't check them all, but make sure your theme is running its setup script on document ready.  Like this (for jQuery).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //run script here
});
```

Also, you could try manipulating the menu CSS.  The id for the div around the menu is "sidr".  Try adding "display:none" or "height:0" and see if the menu still works properly.
You could also speed up page load a little by optimising images - you have about 4.3Mb of images on the index page at the moment - which is a lot.